# rails bootstrap submit button not shown correctly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a rails web app, the login page like this:
[image: login form]

As you can see, only half of the `Submit` button is shown at the bottom. Here is the `html.erb` code:

```ruby
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html:   { role: "form" }) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <%= f.label :account_numb, '请输入学号或工号：' %>
        <%= f.text_field :account_numb, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group required">
        <%= f.label :password, '密码：' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </div>
      <% end -%>

      <%= f.submit  t('.sign_in', default: "Sign in"), class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

I checked the scss file is like this:

```
$btn-primary-color:              #fff;
$btn-primary-bg:                 $brand-primary;
$btn-primary-border:             $gray-lighter;
  .btn-primary {
   &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &:active:hover, &:active:focus {
   background: $brand-light !important;
   border-colorbackground: $brand-light !important;
     }
   }
```

I googled but with no luck, maybe this is just a newbie mistake, but please help.
PS: I used a Devise template for this app, the template works fine. The only thing I could think of is I did a "bundle update".

Comment: It looks like the height of the div surrounding it might be cutting it off. Can you send an inspectable snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about rails, but you can try something like this:

```
.btn-block {
    padding: 10% 0;
    /* define here */
}
```

Moreover, you can also define additional values of width, height etc for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I made a mistake by defining a "input" style in the CSS file. Silly me!

Comment: @user2582234 Nothing, everyone does it :)